# How Does Grails include Source Jars?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, grails

The Grails Eclipse plugin provides the ability to download source jars:

[image]

I turns out that some source jars are not downloaded even if you have the plugin is you BuildConfig like Tomcat:

[image]

Is there a better option than downloading each required source jar myself and include it? Why is downloading source jars not downloading all the sources jars used in my project?

I use Grails 2.3.6

Answer (score 2):

Try to use : **eclipse-scripts plugin**

```
grails install-plugin eclipse-scripts
```

Comment: What should I do with this plugin?